# EmberJs 1.5.x change log url

Tags: ember.js

Where can i find ember v1.5.x changelog, there was an update on the 23/04/2014, that is causing some strange behaviour in my application

I have visited http://emberjs.com/blog/ and found nothing, 
I also know that it is a minor change to 1.5 1.6 isnt scheduled for release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changelog is located [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.5.1/CHANGELOG.md), you can generally find it on the [release page](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/release).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe here:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

or you can see all commits, comments, versions related to the changelog file

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commits/master/CHANGELOG.md